# how to perform a task on every file in a folder python

Tags: python, loops, histogram

i have generated many text files that all contain a list of floats. The length of each list varies for each file. I want to generate a histogram for each file. Therefore, I want to iterate over all txt files in a directory and print a histogram for each. So far I have tried this code, but to no avail:

```
for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        numbers = f.read().strip()
        n, bins, patches = hist(numbers, 100, normed=1, histtype='bar')
        setp(patches, 'facecolor', 'g', 'alpha', 0.75)
        title('m_score for each complex spike')
        ylabel('number of complex spikes')
        xlabel('m_score')
        show()
```

i have also tried to use:

```
for line in fileinput.input(glob('*.txt')):
```

But here i can only generate one histogram. Any help would be much appreciated, I have always struggled with iterating over files.

Comment: What exactly is not working with the first code sample that you listed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files in a given directory using `os.listdir()` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir); you can then iterate over all the files and get the data.

It seems that in the code you posted that you're overwriting the `patches` in each iteration, which might be why you're getting only one histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import os

directory = os.path.join("/","path") # directory that contains your files
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".txt"):
           with open(file, 'r') as f:
               numbers = f.read().strip()
               n, bins, patches = hist(numbers, 100, normed=1, histtype='bar')
               setp(patches, 'facecolor', 'g', 'alpha', 0.75)
               title('m_score for each complex spike')
               ylabel('number of complex spikes')
               xlabel('m_score')
               show()
```